# inserting cells between existing cells in excel

Tags: excel

Is there a way to automatically insert new cells (with date values) between existing cells in Microsoft excel. For example:

```
-Date- 
1/1/2018 
1/2/2018 
1/5/2018
```

I would like to insert 2 new cells (1/3/2018 and 1/4/2018) between 1/2/2018 and 1/5/2018

Comment: How automatic? You would need VBA, is that ok?

Comment: If this is all of your data, simply drag `1/1/2018` 5 cells down. Excel will create the sequence for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your dates are in Column A, the following VBA code will loop through your column, check if the date value has been incremented by one month, if not, then insert new row and add the next date in the sequence until you get to the end of the Column:

```
Sub Add_Dates()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
i = 2

Do Until ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = ""
'check next rows value
    NextDate = DateAdd("m", 1, ws.Cells(i, 1).Value)
    'add one month to the date
    If ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> NextDate Then
    'if next date is not what we expect
           ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
           'insert row
           ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = NextDate
           'add new date
    End If
    i = i + 1
    'increment
Loop
End Sub
```